# Integrable function $f$ such that $F'(x)\ne f(x)$ where $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\;dt$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there an example of an integrable function $f$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $F'(x)\ne f(x)$ where $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\;dt$?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq a$ and $f(a)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can always modify $f$ on a set of zero measure, so for example on the set {x}. Then $F'(x)$ won't change but you can choose $f(x)$ as you please.

Comment: Of course, it's worth noting that not every modification on a set of zero measure will keep the function *Riemann* integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[-1,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\neq0\\1&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $F$ is the null function, but $F'(0)\neq f(0)$.